# Copy folders when copying list items from source to destination

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-api

This is my code to copy files in a list from source to destination. Using the code below I am only able to copy files but not folders. Any ideas on how can I copy the folders and the files within those folders?

```
using (SPSite objSite = new SPSite(URL))
            {
                using (SPWeb objWeb = objSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList objSourceList = null;
                    SPList objDestinationList = null;

                    try
                    {
                        objSourceList = objWeb.Lists["Source"];
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error opening source list");
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        objDestinationList = objWeb.Lists["Destination"];
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error opening destination list");
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }

                    string ItemURL = string.Empty;
                    if (objSourceList != null && objDestinationList != null)
                    {
                        foreach (SPListItem objSourceItem in objSourceList.Items)
                        {
                            ItemURL = string.Format(@"{0}/Destination/{1}", objDestinationList.ParentWeb.Url, objSourceItem.Name);
                            objSourceItem.CopyTo(ItemURL);
                            objSourceItem.UnlinkFromCopySource();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what worked for me. I had to move folders from spweb to another.

```
private static void RecursiveCopy(SPList objSourceList, SPFolder objSourceFolder, SPFolder objDestinationFolder)
        {
            SPListItemCollection objItems = ((SPDocumentLibrary)objSourceList).GetItemsInFolder(objSourceList.DefaultView, objSourceFolder);

            foreach (SPListItem objItem in objItems)
            {
                //If it's a file copy it.
                if (objItem.FileSystemObjectType == SPFileSystemObjectType.File)
                {

                    byte[] fileBytes = objItem.File.OpenBinary();
                    string DestinationURL = string.Format(@"{0}/{1}", objDestinationFolder.Url, objItem.File.Name);

                    //Copy the file.
                    SPFile objDestinationFile = objDestinationFolder.Files.Add(DestinationURL, fileBytes, true);
                    objDestinationFile.Update();
                }
                else
                {
                    string dirURL = string.Format(@"{0}/{1}", objDestinationFolder.Url, objItem.Folder.Name);
                    SPFolder objNewFolder = objDestinationFolder.SubFolders.Add(dirURL);
                    objNewFolder.Update();

                    //Copy all the files in the sub folder
                    RecursiveCopy(objSourceList, objItem.Folder, objNewFolder);
                }
            }
        }

public static void CopyListItems(string SourceSiteURL, string DestinationSiteURL, string ListName)
        {
            string DestinationURL = string.Empty;

            using (SPSite SourceSite = new SPSite(SourceSiteURL))
            {
                using (SPWeb SourceWeb = SourceSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    using (SPSite DestinationSite = new SPSite(DestinationSiteURL))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb DestinationWeb = DestinationSite.OpenWeb())
                        {
                            DestinationWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                            //Get the QA Forms Document libarary from the source web
                            SPList objSourceList = SourceWeb.Lists[ListName];

                            SPList objDestinationList = null;

                            try
                            {
                                objDestinationList = DestinationWeb.Lists[ListName];
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                //Create a list in the destination web
                                DestinationWeb.Lists.Add(ListName, string.Empty, SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary);
                            }

                            objDestinationList = DestinationWeb.Lists[ListName];

                            //Recursively copy all the files and folders
                            RecursiveCopy(objSourceList, objSourceList.RootFolder, objDestinationList.RootFolder);



                            DestinationWeb.Update();
                            DestinationWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

this copies all the files and folders recursively.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

If you are copying to a destination that is located within the same SPWeb, you can try the following.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://urltosite"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                //get the folder from the source library
                SPFolder sourceFolder = web.GetFolder("Documents/Folder 1");

                //get the folder to the destination
                SPFolder destinationFolder = web.GetFolder("New Library");

                sourceFolder.CopyTo(destinationFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + sourceFolder.Name);

            }
        }
```

Sadly I don't think this works when copying a folder to a different SPWeb or SPSite.

Answer (score 0):

SPList.Items only returns non-folder items. You can use SPList.Folders to iterate all of the folders in a list. So if you did the same foreach loop, only using:

`foreach (SPListItem objSourceFolderItem in objSourceList.Folders)`

You would then get all of the folders. To properly move the folder and all of its contents, you would use `objSourceFolderItem.Folder.CopyTo(ItemUrl)`.

I've tried this using a list with only one level of folders (pair it with a foreach loop to get all of the items in the root folder), and it worked for me in SP2007. I believe SPList.Folders gets all of the folders in the entire list, not just the ones in the root folder, so if you end up breaking the list with a multi-level folder system, then an alternative to try might be:

`foreach (SPFolder objSourceFolderItem in objSourceList.RootFolder.SubFolders)`

Since those are already SPFolder objects, you can just use `objSourceFolderItem.CopyTo(ItemUrl)`.